# Exception error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers.preprocessing'" & 'official.legacy'

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, object-detection

Consider:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cdelaney\Documents\TensorflowTraining\tfod\Lib\site-packages\object_detection\models\ssd_efficientnet_bifpn_feature_extractor.py", line 36, in <module>
    from official.legacy.image_classification.efficientnet import efficientnet_model
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'official.legacy'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cdelaney\Documents\TensorflowTraining\models\research\object_detection\builders\model_builder_tf2_test.py", line 24, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import model_builder
  File "C:\Users\cdelaney\Documents\TensorflowTraining\tfod\Lib\site-packages\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 70, in <module>
    from object_detection.models import ssd_efficientnet_bifpn_feature_extractor as ssd_efficientnet_bifpn
  File "C:\Users\cdelaney\Documents\TensorflowTraining\tfod\Lib\site-packages\object_detection\models\ssd_efficientnet_bifpn_feature_extractor.py", line 38, in <module>
    from official.vision.image_classification.efficientnet import efficientnet_model
  File "C:\Users\cdelaney\Documents\TensorflowTraining\tfod\Lib\site-packages\official\vision\image_classification\efficientnet\efficientnet_model.py", line 37, in <module>
    from official.vision.image_classification import preprocessing
  File "C:\Users\cdelaney\Documents\TensorflowTraining\tfod\Lib\site-packages\official\vision\image_classification\preprocessing.py", line 25, in <module>
    from official.vision.image_classification import augment
  File "C:\Users\cdelaney\Documents\TensorflowTraining\tfod\Lib\site-packages\official\vision\image_classification\augment.py", line 31, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.preprocessing import image_preprocessing as image_ops
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers.preprocessing'
```

I have installed all the required packages and the code works fine in [Colaboratory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Jupyter#Industry_adoption). I am trying to run it in a virtual environment on my PC and am getting this error running:

```
python object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py
```

Comment: Some of incorrect modules missing or incorrect module imports in your environment. The error message indicate no module named ‘official.legacy’ which may not be installed correctly with your environment.
You need to install all the required packages and Check if the required modules official or others are present in your environment. If they are missing, you need to reinstall or clone the required repository.